# Grub Rescue / attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 (latest LTS version) on an old computer (Toshiba satellite). I am in the middle of rebooting process and I have the 'attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0'. I saw a lot of answers that says that I should write this

**grub rescue > set root=(hd0,msdos5)**

**grub rescue > set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub**

**grub rescue > insmod normal**

**grub rescue > normal**

I wrote it and I also set the prefix to **/usr/lib/grub**, but nothing is solvinf my issue.
Note:
When I installed the OS I asked to erase the disk and install ubuntu.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: I would suggest boot *live* media & `fsck` or file-system check your partition(s).  When I've come across this issue; it's usually a *logical* error or like on a file-system that once fixed (with `fsck`) has gone away.. I'd also suggest checking the health of your drive(s) using the inbuilt SMART capacity of them (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to mention that when I used to partition the disk in the installation process, it works fine except I get the grub error 'normal.mod file not found'. So, I thought that I would solve that problem and it would solve the normal file problem